# How does using attribute in layer navigation with option filterable with results trigger?

Tags: magento

How does the attribute using in layer navigation with option filterable with results triggers. 
On console i can see this `http://192.168.1.9/crown/index.php/products/refrigeration/back-bar-fridges/door_type/glass-door.html?isLayerAjax=1` being called and it's returning the `layer` and `listing` data which is chaning the content of the page and filtering is working.

My question is, from where can i see this actin being triggered ? and it's obtaining the result ?.

[ The actual problem i'm facing is that, with jQuery i am transforming this block(filtering layer) to other places and it doesn't work via ajax. ]

Answer (score 0):

`isLayerAjax=1` isn't added by Magento, do you have any extensions installed that modify the layer?

Comment: how do i know that, i have installed few of the extensions but none is related to layer navigation. i am trying to figure it out actually how does it triggers ? works ?